# VSCode run script before python initialization

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

While changing the path of python interpreter on VSCode, I encoutered the following error:
[An Invalid Python interpreter is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47bLr.png)

Before changing the interpreter, I need to run an init script on the shell, something like the one below

```
source myInit.sh
```

I run the above shell command on the VSCode terminal and then change the python interpreter but get the error above. The python interpreter can only be used after I have ran the above script, and I am pretty sure that the python interpreter works fine after running init script.

I did try using initialization script feature of VSCode, but the feature is still in [developement](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/141) for VS Code server.

Comment: run the script before starting VSC and start VSC from the same terminal

Comment: I use VSC remote to ssh, cant access shell b4

Comment: then emulate the run command generated by VSC in the script and `attach` to the process, same socket number